# Convert a column into time in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, time, dataframe

I am reading a csv file into pandas DataFrame. One of the columns in the csv file is time stored as string in the format `'09:53:00 AM'`.

I need to convert this column into a time column in the DataFrame. The reason is that I need to filter that column based on time - for instance I want to filter the data based on time greater 9:00:00 AM and less than 02:00:00 PM.

Please note that dates are in a separate column. What I have is following:

```
Col 1,Col 2(date),Col3(time)
AAA,01/29/2015,9:23:00 AM
BBB,02/18/2015,3:07:00 PM
```

I need to get result as follows: only the record containing AAA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `parse_dates` option of [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('date.csv', parse_dates=['Col3(time)'])
```

and the column `Col3(time)` will be parsed as dates. To perform selection using the time information alone, you can make use of the [`dt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dt-accessor) accessor available to datetime-like columns:

```
t0, t1 = pd.to_datetime(['9:00:00 AM', '02:00:00 PM']).time
print df[(df['Col3(time)'].dt.time > t0) & (df['Col3(time)'].dt.time < t1)]
```

Output:

```
  Col 1  Col 2(date)          Col3(time)
0   AAA   01/29/2015 2015-09-15 09:23:00
```

Comment: Yeah, but I have 2 columns - one is dates and the other is time. I only need to convert the column with time represented in string to time column, not the dates.